# sync two or more iframe sites

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, synchronization

I'm trying to make a page that have 2 `iframe`'s with websites, and to scroll one site according to the other scrolling.

For example - if scroll in one site to the bottom of the page - the will scroll to the bottom too.

This is what I wrote by far, but it doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></SCRIPT>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function()
{

//option 1
$("#div1").scroll(function () { 
        $("#div2").scrollTop($("#div1").scrollTop());
        $("#div2").scrollLeft($("#div1").scrollLeft());
    });
$("#div2").scroll(function () { 
        $("#div1").scrollTop($("#div2").scrollTop());
        $("#div1").scrollLeft($("#div2").scrollLeft());
    });

//option 2
$('#div1').contents().scroll(function(){
    $('#div2').contents().scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
}); 
$('#div2').contents().scroll(function(){
    $('#div1').contents().scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
});
//option 3
$('#div1').contentWindow.onscroll = function(e) {
   $('#div2').contentWindow.scrollTop = $('#div1').contentWindow.scrollTop;
   $('#div2').contentWindow.scrollLeft = $('#div1').contentWindow.scrollLeft;
};
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="div1" name="div1" src="http://www.w3schools.com"> style="overflow:auto;height:500px;width:500px;border:1px solid black;">

</iframe>

<iframe id="div2" name="div2" src="http://www.w3schools.com"> style="overflow:auto;height:500px;width:500px;border:1px solid black;">

</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```